# How to manage orders and time zones related issues?

Tags: sql, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, sql-server-2008-r2

In an eCommerce app,

**Scenario 1**

Assume the server is in NY, USA and the client is in Tokyo, Japan. Client makes an order and it needs to be delivered in 10 days. In the scenario there are two times zones NY, USA and Tokyo, Japan and there is the 10-day promise.

1. When client makes the order how many time zone details are entered to database?
2. I was told by a colleague that i have to consider about UTC but how that fits in to this?
3. When I calculate 10 days, based on whose time zone the 10 days needs to be calculated?
4. Could any one give me a GOOD link that shows how this is handled?

Comment: UTC ( Coordinated Universal Time ) is the word. Also, take a look at https://github.com/nodatime/nodatime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get any reasonably sane implementation, you should store the dates as UTC. That is a linear time that is independent of time zones and daylight savings time.

When you read the time from the database and display it to the user, you should convert it to their local time zone. In .NET you can use a `TimeZoneInfo` object to convert a date to a specific time zone.

> When client makes the order how many time zone details are entered to
>   database?

You only need to store the UTC time in the database. That is an exact point in time, that you can later convert to any local time.

> When I calculate 10 days, based on whose time zone the 10 days needs
>   to be calculated?

That depends on how those 10 days are defined. You can just add 10 days to the UTC time, and you get a point in time that is exactly 240 hours later. That means that you may in practice have only nine days to make the delivery, depending on when the order is placed, and what times of day you can make a delivery.

Those ten days could also be defined as calendar days, then the entire tenth day would be included, e.g. if a user places an order at 2015-07-02 03:26, it should arrive before 2015-07-12 23:59 in his time zone.

Answer (score 1):

You need to always store your date time in `UTC`. You can get the current `UTC` time by calling [`GETUTCDATE()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178635.aspx) function.

So if you have a field like `OrderDate` to store date and time of the order, you can calculate the delivery date by using [`DATEDADD`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) function. If needed in your design, you can store the result into another column.

Example:

```
DECLARE @OrderDate DATETIME
SET @OrderDate = '20150702 15:35:21'

SELECT  @OrderDate AS OrderDate
        ,DATEADD(DAY, 10, @OrderDate) AS DeliveryDate
```

Output

```
OrderDate                  DeliveryDate
2015-07-02 15:35:21.000    2015-07-12 15:35:21.000
```

When you want to display the date and time, it should be displayed by local time of the user. You need to format the date in your presentation layer. Although you have functions in SQL Server to handle that but don't format it in database layer.

Answer (score 1):

You can store the time in UTC or common format (YOUR SERVER TIMEZONE). When you display the time it will be converted to Japan (as your case scenario). Your backend have time in your server timezone so you can use it for calculate the time.

for add 10 days.
Convert the time to server and add 10 days.

Do all calculation this way, it will works.

I have used this same method previously in some codebase and this work fine.